# Django REST: Serializer lookup by UUID

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm creating this simple shopping API in Django REST.

Internally I'm using IDs for foreign key constraints, while `guuids` are brought to the outside world.

For the checkout procedure, the user provides a list of article IDs he is willing to purchase. The object in the POST data thus looks as follows:

```
{
  assets: [
    {
       'product': 'd9d5044d-2284-4d15-aa76-2eee3675035b',
       'amount': 4
    },
    ....
  ]
}
```

I'm using the following ticket/asset models:

```
# Ticket
class Ticket(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='tickets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


# Assets
class Asset(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, related_name='assets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock_item = models.ForeignKey(Stock, related_name='stock_item', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
```

And the serializers look as follows:

```
# Asset serializer
class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = ('stock_item', 'amount')


# Ticket serializer
class TicketSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    assets = AssetSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ('uuid', 'owner', 'assets', )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

When posting an object of the type specified above, the following error is presented:

```
{"assets":[{"stock_item": ["Invalid type. Expected PK, received string"]}]}
```

Which I can't seem to solve, how do I instruct the serializer to use the `uuid` as the lookup value? I solved a similar problem on view-level earlier by using the `lookup_field` member, but that doesn't seem to solve it. Any suggestions?
Enter code here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, a [SlugRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) should be able to find the correct related object.

```py
class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ticket = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='uuid',
        queryset=Ticket.objects.all() # Might be redundant with read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = ('ticket', 'stock_item', 'amount')
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to get the SlugRelatedField serializer, upon read, to return the compact hex representation instead of that annoying thing with the dashes in the middle? :)

Comment: @BjornW I'm not really sure what you mean with "compact hex representation". If you don't want a slug field, you should probably use something else than a slug field.

Comment: As far as I know (and stackoverflow) there is no other sane alternatives to PrimaryKeyRelatedField than SlugField, if you want to do a related field on something else than PrimaryKey. It's a major limitation I'd say. So, SlugField is usually recommended for this, but it has the weakness that it can't specify a field by Field, like PrimaryKeyRelatedField can do (pk_field can be set to UUIDField(format='hex') for example, but slug_field is only a string). To answer your question: compact hex for UUIDs look better than the dashed default in APIs sometimes.

Comment: As a FYI for anybody else with the same problem. I simply sub-classed SlugRelatedField and added an override for to_representation, with return getattr(obj, self.slug_field).hex

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @BjornW's comment:

```
class UUIDRelatedField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):
    slug_field = 'uuid'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(slug_field=self.slug_field, **kwargs)


    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return getattr(obj, self.slug_field).hex
```